# WordPress Protected Page doesn't redirect after reCaptcha

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

Since a few months I keep getting a redirect freeze on every password protected page I have. After inputting the password and clicking the reCaptha the page freezes on white and does not redirect any further. After refreshing the page or going to the page via the homepage it works.

Can someone help me fix this error.

System Information :

- WordPress 4.9 (I always update )
- No plugins are used. And if I was using any I elliminated the cause
  by deleting the plugin(s)
- It has nothing to do with the server configuration because it worked a few months before.
- THe WordPress Forum is NOT capable of fixing this because they
  reffered me to StackOverflow.
- It is not a specific piece of code that goes wrong it has something to do
- with the redirection AFTER typing th password of the protected page
  and then clicking the reCaptcha Ï'm not a robot" checkbox and clicking OK.

Several people have had the same problem but it was caused by a specific plugin that I am not using nor did I ever use it.

For more info you can contact me through my account.

Comment: there is absolute no way of knowing how your system is configured. What WordPress version are you using, are you using plugins? What is your server configuration, ... You need to update this in your question. But maybe you should go to some WordPress forum.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please show us the relevant code (Edit your question and add the code)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).